# How can I recreate this emitting/rigid body/force field animation?

Tags: animation, particles, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields, rigidbody

I was wondering is it possible to make this kind of animation with this effect? [image]

As I understand, its the particle system emitter + force field and rigid body? but whenever I give the mesh a rigid body, it won't affect anything in the particle system. So the objects still overlap each other. idk maybe its force field probem but I am still very noob to blender so any help would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: hello, do you have only several objects? you don't need a particle system if you just have several objects...

Comment: @moonbots hi! yep, I need only 10, but I thought I should use particle system so they could emit like that

Comment: maybe try rigid body and force field, with a 0 gravity?

Comment: perhaps you can use boids?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create your pill, give it *Rigid Body* physics (*Active*), disable any gravity in the *Scene Properties* panel, enable the object's rigid body *Animated* option for several frames, animate a short rotation then disable *Animated* and let the physic play so that it continues its rotation, create a *Force Field (Force* type), here I gave it a force of -200. Then link-duplicate your object and *Delta Transform* it, the copies should collide like that:

[image]