# How can I simulate water molecules?

Tags: animation, physics

I'm trying to use Particle system to simulate water molecules, like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iB7tLjqsKMY  or https://phet.colorado.edu/sims/html/states-of-matter-basics/latest/states-of-matter-basics_en.html . But i don't know how to shake or wiggle the molecules. I'd like to make something very similar.

Comment: maybe my answer here will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237249/how-can-i-recreate-this-emitting-rigid-body-force-field-animation/237276#237276

Comment: [Distributed interaction visualization](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/238383/60486) - you may find it useful to start making a Python solution

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

I am using geometry nodes for this (which for sure will be or is already the better particle system) and with this node setup:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]

```
Note: of course you can do this better and play around with the values a bit, but i think it is a good starting point
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Was the model created in Blender 3.0 ? With all this tips, I think I can create a good model. Tks

Comment: The model was just 3 spheres and then I joined the objects